# Option hide on second selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I facing a problem in HTML and JavaScript, when I select color it's work fine but when I select any Cell option red box and its disappear from screen
also check my screen shot.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Select Box</title>
<style>
    .box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #228B22; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option>Choose Color</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">
        <select>
           <option>Cell One</option>
           <option>Cell Two</option>
           <option>Cell Three</option>
           <option>Cell Four</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also run this code live on https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You select both selectors with sigle query. I would give individual ID or Class to selectors to resolve the conflict.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Select Box</title>
        <style>
            .box {
                color: #fff;
                padding: 20px;
                display: none;
                margin-top: 20px;
            }
            .red {
                background: #ff0000;
            }
            .green {
                background: #228b22;
            }
            .blue {
                background: #0000ff;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#color-selector")
                    .change(function () {
                        $(this)
                            .find("option:selected")
                            .each(function () {
                                var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
                                if (optionValue) {
                                    $(".box")
                                        .not("." + optionValue)
                                        .hide();
                                    $("." + optionValue).show();
                                } else {
                                    $(".box").hide();
                                }
                            });
                    })
                    .change();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <select id="color-selector">
                <option>Choose Color</option>
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="red box">
            <select>
                <option>Cell One</option>
                <option>Cell Two</option>
                <option>Cell Three</option>
                <option>Cell Four</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="green box">
            You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here
        </div>
        <div class="blue box">
            You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please share code? thanks

Comment: Here you go. Just added id="color-selector" to first selector, and select by id in jquery

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any value for the options in the red box. So, when you select a value from the red box options, it provides **'undefined'** for optionValue in your script. You can skip operation for selecting the options from the red box by using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("select").change(function () {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else if (typeof optionValue === 'undefined') {
        // Your further operations here
      } else {
        $(".box").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

Just added another else-if condition for **'undefined'** values and didn't any operation for selecting any of red box option.

Answer (score -1):

You'd better use ids for those 'select' elements

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select#my-select-01").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".box").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.green {
  background: #228B22;
}

.blue {
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="my-select-01">
    <option>Choose Color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="red box">
  <select id="my-select-02">
    <option>Cell One</option>
    <option>Cell Two</option>
    <option>Cell Three</option>
    <option>Cell Four</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
```

Comment: Please update your answer to explain why ids should be used. It's not clear.